# Perforce P4 .NET API returns Perforce Password (P4PASSWD) invalid

Tags: .net, api, perforce, p4api.net

I'm writing a VS C# app using the p4api.net to access a P4 server.  The P4V app accesses the depository fine with a given user/password.  Using p4api.net API, the code executed the Connect() & Login() methods without exception using server/user/password strings passed in from a form:

```
  rep.Connection.Connect(options);
  rep.Connection.Login(password, options);
```

Below is the actual code:

```
String conStr = mServerConnection.Text;
String user = mUserText.Text;
String password = mPaswordTxt.Text;
try
{
   Server server = new Server(new ServerAddress(conStr));
   rep = new Repository(server);
   rep.Connection.UserName = user;
   Options options = new Options();
   Options["Password"] = password;
   rep.Connection.Client = new Client();
   rep.Connection.Connect(options);
   rep.Connection.Login(password, options);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   rep = null;
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

However during another call to access the P4 "//depot" root directory, the API call _repository.GetDepotDirs() would return "Perforce Password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset" exception.  Please see code below:

```
public bool Expand()
{
  if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(depotPath))
     return false;
  // if we have the depot path, get a list of the subdirectories from the depot
  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(depotPath))
  {
     IList<string> subdirs = _repository.GetDepotDirs(null, String.Format("{0}/*", depotPath));
```

I read somewhere that I need to set the environmental variable P4TICKETS so I did that in a DOS prompt:

```
p4 set P4TICKETS=C:\Documents and Settings\my_user_name
```

but this didn't resolve the problem.  I'd appreciate your help.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At security level 3, giving the password directly to *Connect* doesn't work.  So I catch the subsequent exception and then call *Login*.  At that point you can save the *Credential.Ticket* returned by *Login* for future calls to *Connect*, under the *Ticket* field in the *options*.

I'm not sure why the subsequent command calls are failing for you, unless your ticket somehow expires, or you've actually disconnected from the server.  You can always call *Connect* again before subsequent commands.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I removed the line "Options["Password"] = password;" and I could logged into the P4 repository.